# Why can't I convert an object (which is really object[]) to string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, casting

I have a field that is of type 'object'.  When I inspect it within the Watch window of visual studio I see its Object[] and when I drill into the elements I see each element is a string.

But when I try to cast this to a String[] I get this error:

> Cannot cast 'MyObject' (which has an actual type of 'object[]') to 'string[]' string[]

Any reason why I can't do this cast?  What is the best way to convert this object to a string array?

Comment: How are you casting your array? As a whole? You need to cast every element of your array individually.

Comment: Yes, he's clearly casting it as a whole.

Comment: Array-of-reference variance is the other way; you can cast something that is **actually** a `string[]` as an `object[]`, but to go the other way it must actually be a `string[]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string[] newarr =  Array.ConvertAll(objects, s => (string)s);
```

--EDIT--

since you've said *I have an `object`* (knowing that it is an `object[]` actually)

```
string[] newarr =  Array.ConvertAll((object[])objects, s => (string)s);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to compile . . i am getting error: Type inference cannot be inferred . . .

Answer (score 23):

This is a particularly confusing feature of C#. Here's the deal.

Throughout this discussion we assume that the element type of an array is a reference type, not a value type.

C# supports *unsafe array covariance*. That means that if you have an array of string, you can convert it to an array of object, because a string can be converted to an object:

```
string[] a1 = { "hello", "goodbye" };
object[] a2 = a1; // Legal
```

If you then try to get an element out of a2, it works:

```
object o3 = a2[0];
```

That's legal because `a2[0]` is really `a1[0]`, which is a string, which is convertible to object.

However, if you attempt to *write* to the array then you'll get an error *at runtime*:

```
a2[0] = new object();
```

This fails at runtime because `a2` is *really* an array of strings, and you can't put a non-string into an array of strings.

So C# is already horribly broken; it is possible to write a program that compiles and looks normal but suddenly crashes with a type exception at runtime because you tried to put an object into an array of objects that is not actually an array of objects.

The feature you want is *even more broken than that*, and thank goodness C# does not support it. The feature you want is:

```
object[] a4 = { "Hello" };
string[] a5 = a4;
```

That would be unsafe array *contravariance*. It breaks horribly like this:

```
a4[0] = new Customer(); // Perfectly legal 
string s6 = a5[0];
```

And now we just copied a *Customer* into a variable of type *string*.

You should avoid any kind of array covariance or contravariance; array contravariance is, as you've discovered, not legal, and array covariance is making little time bombs in your program that go off unexpectedly. **Make your arrays of the right type to begin with.**

Comment: I agree with most of what you say, but I disagree that array contravariance is _even more_ broken than array covariance - they seem like perfectly dual situations.  With array contravariance, you could read and write to the object array, write to the string array, and read from the string array as long as an object of a different type wasn't written to that location through the object array.  With covariance, you could read and write to the string array, read from the object array, and write to the object array as long as you're inserting a string in that location.

Comment: @kvb: I take your point. I say that it is "even more broken" because in the covariant case, the broken scenario is: conversion-followed-by-write fails. But since many people use arrays as *effectively* read-only arrays -- they only write when the array is created -- there is no conversion-followed-by-write, there is only conversion followed by read. That is, it can *only* break if there was a *write* following the conversion. But the contravariant case can break on *any* read after the conversion; the array might not have been all strings to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

```
object[] original = new object[]{"1", "2"};
//some code in between here
object obj = original ;
object[] objArray = (object[])obj;
string[] newArray = new string[objArray.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < newArray; i++)
{
  newArray[i] = (string)objArray[i];
}
```

Other answers here are showing you quicker/shorter ways of doing the conversion.  I wrote the whole thing out like this because it shows what's really going on and what needs to happen.  You should use one of the simpler methods in your actual production code.

Comment: hmm . . for some reason your solution is the only one that compiles and works for me . .

Comment: @leora Most everyone else solved a portion of the problem, but not the whole thing.  They solved that portion more cleanly/elegantly.  As I said, this code is designed to show you what needs to happen, even if there is a library method that does half of it for you.

Comment: @Servy `but not the whole thing` are you sure?.

Comment: @L.B You fixed yours on edit.  At first you didn't (i.e. at the time of my post.)  Every other answer still hasn't included the relevant cast from `object` to `object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The rule in object oriented programming is -

"Derived class can always be type casted to base class"   AND
"A Base class can be casted to derived class only if the current instance that base class hold off is actually derived class"

e.g. (A is base and B is derived)

```
A a = new B();  // legal;
B b = (B) a ;   // legal as "a" is actually B (in first statement)
```

illegal :  >

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B) a;  // not legal as "a" is A only.
```

Same thing is applied to Object and String classes. Object is base class and string is Derived class.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the *real* `string[]` to `object[]`.

This is a [Array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Can find a clear example in link.

Answer (score -1):

You should cast each element in the collection and not the collection itself.

```
object[] ovalues = new object[] { "alpha", "beta" };
string[] svalues = ovalues.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: i don't have object[] . .i only have object . . given that I get "Can't resolve Cast"

Comment: I changed the type for you. Test again